# R Cummulative sum and transfer

Tags: r, sum

The data has a positive value to sum over time, grouped by units.  Then the summed value should be transferred to the remaining rows.  The positive value is only on the imds rows.  The summed value needs to be transferred to the maint rows.  If the maint row occurs first for a unit, then the summed value should be zero.  The two bottom plots should show increasing functions.

```
set.seed(2)
nrowsToShow=40
df<-data.frame(time=seq.Date( as.Date("2014/01/01"), length=100, by='1 days' ),
      source=sample(c("imds","maint"),100,replace=T), 
      unit=sample(101:110, 100,replace=T))
nimds=length(df$source[df$source=="imds"])
df$ft=NA
df$ft[df$source=="imds"]=sample(seq(0.5,5,.5),nimds,replace=T)
df<-df[with(df,order(unit,time)),]
head(df,nrowsToShow)
library(zoo)
na_replace <- function(x) {
  na.locf(x,na.rm=FALSE)
}
df$cum_ft=NA
df$cum_ft[df$source=="imds"] <- ave(df$ft[df$source=="imds"], df$unit[df$source=="imds"], FUN=cumsum)
# df$cum_ft <- ave(df$ft, df$unit, FUN=na_replace)
df$cum_ft <- ave(df$cum_ft, df$unit, FUN=na_replace)
df$cum_ft[is.na(df$cum_ft)]=0
head(df,nrowsToShow)
library(ggplot2)
x11()
p0<-ggplot(df[df$source=="imds",],aes(x=time,y=ft,group=unit))+geom_line(col=df$unit[df$source=="imds"])+
    labs(title="IMDS Data") + geom_point(col=df$unit[df$source=="imds"])
p1<-ggplot(df[df$source=="imds",],aes(x=time,y=cum_ft,group=unit))+geom_line(col=df$unit[df$source=="imds"])+
    labs(title="IMDS Data, Sum of data above") + geom_point(col=df$unit[df$source=="imds"])
p2<-ggplot(df,aes(x=time,y=cum_ft,group=unit))+geom_line(col=df$unit)+
    labs(title="ALL Data, value hold on data above") + geom_point(col=df$unit)
library(gridExtra)
plot_list=list(p0,p1,p2)
do.call(grid.arrange,plot_list)
```

Never mind, the "error" was located and updated, the above code produces the expected results.

Comment: @agstudy  OK, I undeleted it.  I deleted it because I thought I corrected the error(s), but I continue to get errors that I don't understand.  Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Had a typo in the ave command, the original and corrected are in the code above.